# SuiteQL cannot includes keyword 'DISTINCT'?

Tags: sql, netsuite, suitescript

I keep on getting an error when I try to use the `distinct` keyword with SuiteQL.

This is my code:

```js
var bannedItemIdArr = [];
var querySQL = "SELECT DISTINCT item.ID AS idRAW /*{id#RAW}*/ FROM item, (SELECT itemMember.parentitem AS parentitem, itemMember.parentitem AS parentitem_join, itemMember.ID AS ID, item_0.itemtype AS itemtype, itemMember.item AS item, item_0.itemtype AS itemtype_crit, item_0.isinactive AS isinactive_crit FROM itemMember, item item_0 WHERE itemMember.item = item_0.ID(+)) itemMember_SUB WHERE item.ID = itemMember_SUB.parentitem(+) AND ((UPPER(item.itemtype) IN ('ASSEMBLY') AND UPPER(itemMember_SUB.itemtype_crit) IN ('INVTPART', 'ASSEMBLY') AND itemMember_SUB.isinactive_crit = 'T' AND NVL(item.isinactive, 'F') = 'F'))";
var myPagedResults = query.runSuiteQLPaged({ query: querySQL, pageSize: 1000, });
```

The error:

> Search error occurred: Invalid or unsupported search

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Please reopen this question:  it contains enough detail to be answered.

Comment: Additional details:  


It works well when runSuiteQLPaged called, 
But It went wrong when I fetch data from the result. 


myPagedResults.fetch({index: 0});//cause error line

Comment: I believe this error had gone with the wind because the keyword 'Distinct' is now being supported for SuiteQL.

You may try this "SELECT DISTINCT Status FROM Transaction" for test purposes in the chrome console or [timdietrich's SuiteQL](https://timdietrich.me/netsuite-suitescripts/suiteql-query-tool/) tool;

Although I still don't know which update fixed such a problem.

Answer (score 2):

So the trick here is to use `group by` and not `distinct`.

e.g.,

```
select item.id
from item
group by item.id
```

That said your query looks  like it is using the old oracle-specific syntax for joins (using (+)) instead of the suite-ql supported ANSI92 syntax of `left join` and `right join`.  Also, you will have to change `nvl` to use the ANSI92 `coalesce`.

Comment: Thanks for your tips.
It works when replacing 'distinct' with 'group by'.

And for the other syntax difference, I will notice it next time.

Comment: Is there a way to select all columns from `item` and still `GROUP BY item.id`? When I try `SELECT item.id, item.* FROM item GROUP BY item.id`, SuiteQL complains "Search error occurred: Invalid or unsupported search".

Comment: In order to do that, you'd have to list out each of the fields that is not being aggregated in the group by like you would in pl/sql or t/sql.

Answer (score 0):

**Have you looked at query.Aggregate?**

| Enum Description | Module |
| --- | --- |
| Holds the string values for aggregate functions supported with the N/query Module. An aggregate function performs a calculation on the column or condition values and returns a single value. Each value in this enum (except MEDIAN) has two variants: distinct (using the _DISTINCT suffix) and nondistinct (using no suffix). The variant determines whether the aggregate function operates on all instances of duplicate values or on just a single instance of the value. For example, consider a situation in which the MAXIMUM aggregate function is used to determine the maximum of a set of values. When using the distinct variant (MAXIMUM_DISTINCT), the aggregate function considers each instance of duplicate values. So if the set of values includes three distinct values that are all equal and all represent the maximum value in the set, the aggregate function lists all three instances. When using the nondistinct variant (MAXIMUM), only one instance of the maximum value is listed, regardless of the number of instances of that maximum value in the set. This enum is used to pass the aggregate function argument to Component.createColumn(options), Component.createCondition(options), Query.createColumn(options), and Query.createCondition(options). | N/query Module |

**Values**

| Value | Description |
| --- | --- |
| AVERAGE | Calculates the average value. |
| AVERAGE_DISTINCT | Calculates the average distinct value. |
| COUNT | Counts the number of results. |
| COUNT_DISTINCT | Counts the number of distinct results. |
| MAXIMUM | Determines the maximum value. If the values are dates, the most recent date is determined. |
| MAXIMUM_DISTINCT | Determines the maximum distinct value. If the values are dates, the most recent date is determined. |
| MEDIAN | Calculates the median value |
| MINIMUM | Determines the minimum value. If the values are dates, the earliest date is determined. |
| MINIMUM_DISTINCT | Determines the minimum distinct value. If the values are dates, the earliest date is determined. |
| SUM | Adds all values. |
| SUM_DISTINCT | Adds all distinct values. |

**Syntax**

```
// Add additional code
...
var myTransactionQuery = query.create({
    type: query.Type.TRANSACTION
});

var myAggColumn = myTransactionQuery.createColumn({
    fieldId: 'amount',
    aggregate: query.Aggregate.AVERAGE
});

myTransactionQuery.columns = [myAggColumn];
...
// Add additional code
```

Comment: Thanks for your tips,
But I think I had not descrip my situation properly,
So I just add more details for my question.

I just wanna use keywords 'DISTINCT' in my SuiteQL, and fetch myPagedResults.
And if I do not use Paged api, do not fetch data, All things goes on well.

I'm not sure of the 'fetch' theory.